# Unknown column in 'where clause', php

Tags: php

I installed something called the "STHS Web Portal" (Here: http://www.simhl.net/node/8)

It's on an older php version and I have been going through and fixing the many small problems that keep coming up in the different files.

I got to one file, and after fixing most the problems, this happens:
`Unknown column 'o.PlayerType' in 'where clause'`

This seems to be the section where the problem is coming from:

```php
$query_GetTransactions = sprintf("SELECT o.*, 'False' as PosG, p.Number, p.Name FROM playerscontractoffers as o, players as p WHERE o.Player=p.Number AND o.PlayerType='player' AND (o.Type='Extension' OR o.Type='Signed') AND o.Approved='True' UNION ALL SELECT o.*, 'True' as PosG, p.Number, p.Name FROM playerscontractoffers as o, goalies as p WHERE o.Player=p.Number AND o.PlayerType='goalie' AND (o.Type='Extension' OR o.Type='Signed') AND o.Approved='True' ORDER BY DateCreated DESC LIMIT 0,50");
$GetTransactions = mysqli_query($connection, $query_GetTransactions) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$row_GetTransactions = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GetTransactions);
$totalRows_GetTransactions = mysqli_num_rows($GetTransactions);
```

I'm quite new to php, and I have no idea what to do. If you need more of the file, please let me know.

Comment: It means there is no column `PlayerType` in your `playerscontractoffers` table in your MySQL database.

Comment: That sounds more like a MySQL error than a PHP error.  What happens when you try to run the same query manually on your database?  Format the query to be more readable to help yourself see and debug it.  What are the table structures you're querying?  Why do you expect that column to be there?

Comment: You shouldn't do your joins and join constraints like that. Use `join` and `on`s. Likely you don't need the `union` either, I'd guess you could use a `case`.

Comment: @user3783243, pretty unclear what you mean with use a `case`, and also pretty irrelevant to the question asked.

Comment: Did you find this version on GitHub: https://github.com/JimToupet/STHS-Web-Portal ?

Comment: @Luuk I'll disagree with your for the following reasons. 1. The `where` issue appears in both queries. 2. The query will take longer to execute because it is twice as large as it needs to be. 3. If you are unclear with case syntax see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html 4. The theta style join here I believe is from 1992 and is known to cause issues either errors or just performance.

Comment: https://github.com/fredyounan/sths-v2-web-portal @Luuk it was actually this one

Comment: @DilIsPickle: The version is was referring to has an install script, a quick search did reveal the presence of 'PlayerType' in this script...